# How to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access to insert data to MS Access?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I was using OleDB before, I was able to run a saved query with parameters. (Commandtype=storedprocedure)

But upon searching some say Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access (DAO?) is a lot faster in terms of insertion (I'm inserting data 1 by 1 around 450k data) now I would like to try this one.

Note: I'm using MS Access 2016.

So far I got this:

```
var ap = new Application();
ap.OpenCurrentDatabase(pathofaccdb);
ap.DoCmd.RunSQL("savedquery"); // not sure how to continue from here.
```

How do I implement a call of saved query with that query having parameters?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.runsql
Seems like RunSQL just takes the whole SQL string, so you'd have to build up the string, with necessary parameters, and then pass it to RunSQL.

Comment: Try `DoCmd.OpenQuery` instead. Are those parameters referencing form controls for input?

Comment: parameters are from an excel file, basically I'm reading a excel file, then get a part of a string, then use that as a parameter